# Compute $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_0^1 (1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}d x$.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to compute
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_0^1 {\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}^{-n}d x.$$

I know that $\lim_{n\to \infty }(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}=e^{-x}$. I'm sure the convergence is uniform, but I have problem to show it. Let $$g_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}-e^{-x}.$$

I have $$g_n'(x)=-\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n-1}+e^{-x},$$
but how can I solve $g_n'(x)=0$ and then find the maximum of $g'_n$ ? I really don't see.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence $(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}$  is a decreasingly monotone sequence of continuous functions which converges pointwise on the compact set $[0,1]$ to the function $e^{-x}$ which is also continuous. Therefore by [Dini'Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) the convergence is also uniform.

Answer (score 3):

Put $y=1+\frac{x}{n}$
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}dx=\int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}ny^{-n}dy=n[\frac{y^{1-n}}{1-n}]_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n}{1-n}((1+\frac{1}{n})^{1-n}-1)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{1-n}((1+\frac{1}{n})^{1-n}-1)=(-1)(\frac{1}{e}-1)=1-\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

I think the easy way is DCT. Note that trivially $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}\leq1
 $$ so $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}dx\leq1
 $$ hence by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we can swap the integral with the limit and so $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}dx
 $$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}dx=\color {red}{1-\frac{1}{e}}.$$

Comment: It is quite clear from the question that he cannot use DCT. It's a too advanced tool

Comment: @b00nheT No one forces him to accept the answer. And, well, DCT is still widely used undergraduate analysis.

Comment: That it is undergraduate analysis is true, but it's still measure theory and not basic first year analysis.

Comment: @b00nheT So you know what tools the OP knows and what is "advanced" or not for him/her. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If someone is attempting the above limit using uniform convergence, then I can be *almost sure* that he is still in first year. But let's not keep this useless discussion going. Your answer is correct and that's it.

Comment: @b00nheT As G. Sassatelli wrote, nobody force him to accept the answer. And note that an answer is not only for the question OP, but for the whole community.

Answer (score 0):

There is e.g. the following elementary way: For $x\geq 0$, 
denote $g(x)=(1+x)^{-1} \in (0,1]$. Then for $n\geq 1$, $0\leq x\leq 1$ we get by the MVT:
$$ \left|g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\right| \ \leq \  \left( \frac{1}{n}\sup_{\xi\geq 0} \left| g'(\xi) +e^{-\xi}  \right| \right)\ \ \left|\frac{x}{n}-0\right| 
 \ \leq \ \frac{1}{n} \times \frac{1}{n} $$
Using the expansion $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$ we obtain:
 $$\left| \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}-e^{-x}\right|=\left|g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-(e^{-x/n})^n\right| \leq \frac{1}{n^2} 
\sum_{k=1}^{n}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{k-1} (e^{-x/n})^{n-k}\leq \frac{1}{n^2} n =\frac{1}{n}$$